# How do I unwrap an Option when it's available or return a default reference value otherwise?

Tags: rust

I want to create a helper function that returns the value of an `Option` if available else it returns the default case.

```
fn get_val(&self) -> &Val {
    return if self.my_val.is_none() {
        &self.default
    } else {
        &self.my_val.unwrap()
    };
}
```

I can't do this because the `unwrap` function's result is short lived.

Comment: The whole docs on `Option` is quite a read, but you might be particularly interested in [unwrap_or method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or).

Comment: This is defiantly interesting but I still have the same issue. which is the result of the function is still fixed to the scope of the function. hence I cannot return the borrow.

Comment: please include an [mcve].

Comment: Applying the duplicate to your specific case: `fn get_val(&self) -> &Val { self.my_val.as_ref().unwrap_or(&self.default) }`.

Comment: Thanks everybody that helped!